# Why wouldn't Jean Jacques cooperate with the U.S. Justice Department for an account under a different name?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

In *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), Jordan Belfort and Swiss banker Jean Jacques discuss hiding Jordan’s
money in a Swiss bank. Jean Jacques says a subpoena from the U.S.
Justice Department would be disregarded, but Jordan points out that
if it pertained to stock fraud, a crime in Switzerland, the bank would
have to cooperate:

> Jean Jacques: Yes. Yes, we would. Mmm-hmm. Assuming the account is
> under your name. **If it were another name, a friend’s, camarade…**
>
> Nikki: Cousin?
>
> Jordan Belfort: Relative? -
>
> Jean Jacques: **Yeah. Hmm**.

Why wouldn't Jean Jacques cooperate with the U.S. Justice Department for an account under a different name?

Comment: Isn't that just asking that Belfort puts the account under someone else's name? No tracking or no record of his name, nothing to give to the authorities?

Comment: The implication seems to be that a warrant would request account details for an account in the name of the suspect. Not for accounts under another name.

Answer (score 3):

You're overthinking this one. The Swiss banker is just saying that they'd be forced to cooperate with a subpoena *in Belfort's name*.

If he operates the account in someone else's name, they can happily ignore any request for his account details (e.g. since he doesn't officially have an account).